# some mui (material ui) elements do not seem to be styled

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I've followed the tutorial here to add material UI to my app: https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started

But some components appear not to be styled and customizing the theme doesn't seem to work either...

I am setting up my theme this way:

```
// theme.ts
import {createTheme} from '@mui/material/styles';

const ourTheme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        h1: {
            fontSize: '3rem',
            color: 'red',
        },
    },
});

export default ourTheme;
```

And I wrap my whole app in a `ThemeProvider` like so:

```
// App.tsx
import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';
import theme from './theme';
import Home from './pages/Home';

const App: React.FC = () => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Home />
    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

and `Home` is just a test page defined this way:

```
// pages/Home.tsx
const Home: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Typography component='h1'>Home</Typography>
            <p>
                Hello to us, and hello to you!
            </p>
            <p>lala!! :{')'}</p>
            <p>
                <Button variant='contained' color='primary'>
                    This does nothing.
                </Button>
            </p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The issue is that the page appears this way:

[image: rendered home page]

While I am expecting the `h1` to be large and red.

I have tried without my custom theme and the `h1` is still unstyled (almost the same as normal text).

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid, it was `variant='h1'` and not `component='h1'`, duh...

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your App like this

```
// App.tsx
import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'; // add this
import theme from './theme';
import Home from './pages/Home';

const App: React.FC = () => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Home />
    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

reference: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#4-global-css-override

Comment: actually I just found the solution, stupid mistake you can see my own answer, but thank you, I had forgotten to include the baseline which is useful